# mysql selection first letter of each word in a cell

Tags: mysql

I would like to return the first letter of each word in a MySQL column called 'initials'.

For example, my table may look like this:

```
|             project_unit              | initials |
+---------------------------------------+----------+
|      Mbita Clinic Rehabilitation      |   MCR    |
| Management Strategy for Thrips Cowpea |   MSTC   |
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think there is not any direct string function of this requirement in mysql inbuilt. Even though if you can achieve also using more than one functions, it will be costly rather than doing it in any programming language. :)

Comment: Looks like you want to find all Uppercase Letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below mentioned function to achieve your requirement.

```
 DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION split_string(split_string varchar(255),my_delimiter varchar(1)) RETURNS varchar(10)
BEGIN
DECLARE temp_string varchar(255);
DECLARE occurance INT;
DECLARE i INT;
DECLARE temp_result varchar(10);
DECLARE final_result varchar(10);
SET temp_result = '';
SET occurance=length(split_string)-length(replace(split_string,' ',''))+1;
  IF occurance > 0 then
    set i=1;
    while i <= occurance do
        set temp_string = (select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(split_string, my_delimiter, i),my_delimiter ,-1));
        set temp_result = CONCAT(temp_result, SUBSTRING(temp_string,1,1));
      set i=i+1;
    end while;
  ELSE
        set temp_result = SUBSTRING(split_string,1,1);
  END IF;
  set occurance=0;
  SET final_result = temp_result;
  RETURN (final_result);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

You can use it like this : 
`SELECT Projcect_unit, split_string(Projcect_unit,' ') as initials FROM main_table;`

Answer (score 1):

Since `MySQL` does not support Regex replacement, you will need to first include UDF (**U**ser **D**efined **F**unction) which you can get from [this](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp) link.

Once you have the regexp_replace function, you can simply use

```
select regexp_replace('Mbita Clinic Rehabilitation', '[a-z ]', '')
```

which would return `MRC`.

Note that the current regex will remove lowercase letter and spaces, but if your field can contains number or any other character you will have to modify the regex.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

`MySql` does not provide such try string operation function so you need create function and call function with query

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `GetUpperCase`(InputString VARCHAR(1024)) RETURNS varchar(1024) CHARSET latin1
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    DECLARE return_string,inputDATA VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE schar VARCHAR(1);
    DECLARE string_length, char_code INT;

    SET string_length = LENGTH(InputString);
    SET inputDATA = InputString ;
    SET return_string = '';
    WHILE string_length > 0 DO
        SET schar = SUBSTRING(inputDATA FROM (-1 * string_length) FOR 1);
        SET char_code = ORD(schar);
        IF char_code >= 65 AND char_code <= 90  THEN
            SET return_string = CONCAT(return_string, schar);
        END IF;
        SET string_length = string_length - 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN return_string;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

and call function with SQL select query

```
mysql> SELECT GetUpperCase("Mbita Clinic Rehabilitation Management Strategy for Thrips Cowpea") AS `initials`;
+----------+
| initials |
+----------+
| MCRMSTC  |
+----------+
```

Comment: the function shows Error when i execute it in mysql

Comment: ohh, was typo mistake.. i was missed `$$` after end of function, i have updated answer, please try now